# htaccess URL rewriting PHP for posts and offers

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i've searched for a long time an answer for my issue, I found a lot of ideas, but I can't figure it out and make it work as I expect..

So, I've a website with

- "/index.php"
- "/posts.php"

What I want is to rewrite the url in order to :
redirect  "/index.php",  "/index.php/"  and  "/index/"  to  "/"

and also :

redirect  "/posts/slug-post-1/"  to "offers.php" but still display  "/posts/slug-post-1/"  in which I would split the url to get the slug of the post.

Thanks

What I've tried is :

`## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]`

`RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]`

It actually display "/offers/" and redirect to "/offers.php"
but when i add a post slug, it doesn't work.

So I've also tried :
`RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]*)$ /posts.php?slug=$1 [L]`

It works only with ctrl+F5 and not a simple refresh.. I don't understand why. This is the same with different brwoser and computer.

Comment: So, if you want urls with extention like this **It actually display `/offers/` and redirect to** `/offers.php`, why uisng htaccess then ? if you want pretty url, your code should look like this with id and slug : `RewriteRule ^posts/(\d+)/([\w-]+)$ /posts.php?q=$1&slug=$2 [L]`  and without id `RewriteRule ^posts/([\w-]+)$ /posts.php?slug=$1 [L]`

Comment: @DLK What does slug resolve to when you're writing the RewriteRule directly to ?slug=$1? I think it should be more like `RewriteRule posts/(.*)$ posts.php [QSA,L]` so any parameter will be passed to the redirect.

Comment: Do you insist on the trailing slashes?

Comment: @Skip both Regex does the same thing, but when you dont have slug after php extention then you should use `[NC,L]`, so, `[QSA,L]` is = `[NC,L]`

Comment: NC is case insensitivity, QSA is for appending query string slugs, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a shot :-)

To redirect "/*index.php*", "/*index.php*/" and "/*index*/" to "/".

```
RewriteRule index(.*)$ / [NC, L]
```

**Edit**: I really urge you not to change the default behaviour of a crucial file like index.php in main folder. There will be unforeseen consequences.

And the other one:

```
RewriteRule posts/slug-post-1(.*)$ offers.php [QSA, NC, L]
```

In your example:

Your `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]` checks if "requests filename" with .php added is a real existing file.

Use `RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` to make sure the targeted file is not skipped, although it is existing. `!-d` would check for directories.

If you want slugs to be added dynamically to the new target, use flag QSA, so [QSA, NC, L] instead of [NC, L], for example. Use the condition before the rule.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a comment - but space is limited.

It looks as if you haven't thought through what you are trying to achieve before trying to implement it.

> What I want is to rewrite the url in order to : redirect "/index.php", "/index.php/" and "/index/" to "/"

I think you need to do a lot more searching. Webservers don't serve up directories, they typically have a lot of machinery in place to service up content when presented with a request where the path maps to a directory to change that to a file, a script, or a special handler.

I suspect you want to rewrite /, /index.php/ and /index/ to /index.php

But I suspect there's more to what you are trying to achieve here - that you also want to deal with any string after the pattern you are seeking to match which is implied in your attempts to deal with /posts.

So it looks as if you are trying to implement 2 front controller patterns. Implementing a single front controller pattern appears to be a bit of a stretch for you. Implementing 2 at the same time is unlikely to turn out well and whatever you do finally implement will likely be very fragile. You're going to need a router in /index.php so that is the right place to handle the /posts/ requests.

But this is only *PART* of the problem you need to solve. Having your PHP code intercepting all requests is rather expensive in terms of CPU and memory (unless you have a really good caching policy implemented on your server and it is sitting behind a caching reverse proxy).